# Grouping items in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group a result set of ektron search results items and output them on screen, I use the following code

```
var groupdResults = 
    from result in response.Results
    orderby result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetDateProperty("/root/FundClosingDate")]
    group result by result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetStringProperty("/root/DeadlineAltText")] 
    into statusGroup
    select new 
    { 
        closingDate =statusGroup.Key,
        count= statusGroup.Count
    };
```

I then add these to a listview: uxSearchResultView.DataSource = groupdResults;

The problem I'm having is that i need to output all the data from the resultset e.g. title,closingdate, etc.., It currently only outputs, e.g.
Closing 2
open 1

really appreciate any help anyone can offer

-----------------------Updated-------------------------------------
I think i have a working solution now, but its kind of messy

```
var groupdResults = from result in response.Results
                                orderby result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetDateProperty("/root/FundClosingDate")]
                                group result by result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetStringProperty("/root/DeadlineAltText")] 
                                into statusGroup
                                    select new 
                                    {
                                        closingDate = statusGroup.Key,
                                        count = statusGroup.Count(),
                                        items = statusGroup.ToList()
                                    };
    List<Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchResultData> SRDATA = new List<Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchResultData>();
            foreach (var result in groupdResults)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.items.Count; i++)
                {
                    SRDATA.Add(result.items[i]);
                }
            }
```

Any input as to a cleaner implementation?
thanks

Comment: statusGroup.First().ClosingDate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Modified)

I think you need a class to capture your results:

```
class GroupResult
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SearchResultData> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The grouping `statusGroup` is an `IEnumerable` of your items, so you can do:

```
var groupdResults = 
    from result in response.Results
    group result by result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetStringProperty("/root/DeadlineAltText")] 
    into statusGroup
    select new GroupResult
    { 
        Status =statusGroup.Key,
        Items = statusGroup.ToList()
    }.ToList();
```

After that you can display the `Items` in any way you wish, like sorted by `Status` and the `Items` sorted by `ClosingDate`.

But maybe it is enough to just sort `response.Results` by status and *then by* closing date.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, on this code "items = statusGroup.Select(g => new {g.title, g.closingdate, ... })"

I am trying to get for example result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetDateProperty("/root/FundClosingDate")] item back in the ".Select", any ideas?

Comment: Then you will arrive at MarcinJuraszek's answer.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Nearly there :) i have content outputing  by putting the items from marcins answer into a new list, the only problem is that i can't output all of the items. I've done the following, but I know .first is wrong, what do I put instead of first to output all the items?

List<Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchResultData> SRDATA = new List<Ektron.Cms.Search.SearchResultData>();
            foreach (var result in groupdResults)
            {
                SRDATA.Add(result.items.First());
            }

Comment: OK, seen your update. I don't understand why you group first and then ungroup again by only saving the `SearchResultData` items in a list. Is the grouping just for ensuring a sort order? Or is there some other proces between the grouping and the creating of list?

Comment: The aim is to group the items by status and then sort by date within each group. I thought I was saving the grouped content, how would I do this. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:

```
select new 
{ 
    closingDate =statusGroup.Key,
    count= statusGroup.Count(),
    items = statusGroup.ToList()
};
```

`items` property will contain items that were assigned to that group in a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using anonymous types I would put that into a new object.

```
var groupdResults = 
from result in response.Results
orderby result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetDateProperty("/root/FundClosingDate")]
group result by result[SearchSmartFormProperty.GetStringProperty("/root/DeadlineAltText")] 
into statusGroup
select new ResultObject
{ 
    closingDate = statusGroup.First().ClosingDate,
    ....
};
```